# Filter result by colPos TYPO3

Tags: typo3

We created an extension for TYPO3, but we want a different result to be displayed in the columns (left right normal etc).

We got it working to filter by page ID. But they all show the result for the entire page, and not only for the column it's being loaded.

How do you filter the result by colPos (found in tt_content).

```
<?php
$pri = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_SELECTgetRows('tx_extendttcontent_pid_banner','tt_content','pid = "'.$activePage.'" AND deleted = 0 AND hidden = 0');
?>
```

we get activePage by $GLOBAL['TSFE']->id;

Comment: You mean you want to load the content according to which column your plugin is inserted in?

Comment: @cascaval Yes! That's exactly what I mean. Do you know how to do this? I made a custom extension, but it loads the content of the entire page, so if I add it to 2 columns, it shows double

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit complicated because it depends on the structure of your extension. However, in the main class of your extension that extends `tslib_pibase` class, you should have the plugin data available in the `$this->cObj->data` array. Therefore, something like this should work:

```
<?php
    $colPos = $this->cObj->data['colPos'];
    $pri = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_SELECTgetRows('tx_extendttcontent_pid_banner','tt_content','pid = "'.$activePage.'" colPos='.$colPos.' AND deleted = 0 AND hidden = 0');
?>
```

**NOTE**: The SQL query doesn't take into account access data. At very least you should include a check for `starttime` and `endtime` so that you don't load content that shouldn't be displayed. If you are writing extension that will have global usage, you should probably load the content different way so that even FE user access rights are taken into account.

Comment: When echo'ing $colPos, I don't get any result... What part of the code do you wish to see in order to help out?

Comment: 1. Debug `$this->cObj->data` to see what's inside. 2. Post the significant part(s) of the class where your try to use the code.

Comment: Hey man, thanks. $colPos = $this->cObj->data[colPos]; did the trick!

Comment: Right, my mistake. I'll fix it in my answer as well.

Comment: $this->cObj->enableFields('tt_content'); will check for starttime, endtime, hidden, deleted and fe.user access. http://api.typo3.org/typo3v4/current/html/classtslib__c_obj.html#a18d6f17ed58e3bb574126d4664d84619